# SharePoint slow page load

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, performance

We've got a new instance of SharePoint 2016 running on 36gb for the WFE and 14gb for the SQL Server.

We're noticing that home.aspx takes around 4-5 seconds to load and we're having a hard time tracking down why.

I've checked the Distributed Cache and it's allocated 2.8GB, it's using a managed account as recommended, I've tried to restart it, not seeing a change and nothing I can find in the ULS logs.

I've enabled Developer Dashboard for further analysis:

[Server Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPzn2.jpg)

Looking at the scopes, I see [two that seems a lot longer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQITx.jpg) than the others by a large margin but I don't know how to interpret the results.

This is the [SQL output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjCUg.jpg)

This is what I'm seeing in the [Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfJ0v.jpg), most things are coming from the browser cache but Home.aspx itself is taking much longer than anything else.

We don't have blob cache enabled or others, just Distributed Service which appears to be running as expected.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I have 3 list view webparts for the same document library on the home page. When I remove them, my page loads in 200ms, when i put them back, it loads in 2500ms.

I'm pretty confident this is the issue, but we need those lists on the home page. Is it possible to optimize this? Caching the 3 views, indexing the list columns, blob cache, page cache?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your issue.  But my new install was running slow.  I stopped and started the Distributed Cache Service in the Services on Server page in CA.

Comment: Yea there was a lot of recommendations around the server, we looked into it (restarting it, settings, size) and it didn't seem to be the issue. It appears that having 3 list view webparts on the page might be the problem

Comment: If so, maybe just adjust the item limit in the wepart settings so it doesn't have to fetch all of them.  If someone wants to edit the list, they can go to the list proper.